# TypeScript - Pattern for passing object to function & setting defaults

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm fairly new to TS and wanted some advice on how to pass an object literal to a method in the most efficient manner.

E.g. (called in html)

```
<script>
    app.setOptions({
        width: 820,
        height: 450,
        bgColor: '#fff'
    });
</script>
```

In main.ts

```
module app {

    app.setOptions = function(options: { width: number, height: number, bgColor: string}) {
        options.width   = options.width || 600,
        options.height  = options.height || 300,
        options.bgColor = options.bgColor || '#fff';

        initializeApp(options);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This works fine, although I'm warned about 'the property setOptions does not exist on type 'typeof app'. I'm going to add loads more options too.

Comment: `options.width   = options.width || 600` What if the width is supposed to be 0?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The width won't be 0, it's setting a HTML5 canvas width. When called they can set the width or it will use the default width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting default value for TypeScript object passed as argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314806/setting-default-value-for-typescript-object-passed-as-argument)