# Strange function arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I found this piece of code that I don't fully understand. To be precise, I'm talking about those function arguments:

```
function defaultPort({ port=123, user='test' }: Object = {}) {
}
```

I thought it was a different kind of deconstructing, but apparently it's not. Also, I can't run this code in Node, so I guess it needs some kind of module to use it properly.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: For what it's worth: That's not (vanilla) JavaScript.

Comment: It's TypeScript, you need to use `tsc` to turn it into JS.

Comment: *Parts* of that are like modern JavaScript, but the `: Object = {}` at the end, if it's been quoted correctly, is not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: TypeScript's playground doesn't like it, complains that `Object` doesn't have `port` and `user`. But yeah, could be, with more declarations or something.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder interesting, it looks like the stuff in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314806/setting-default-value-for-typescript-object-passed-as-argument. OP, could you be more specific about where you found it?

Comment: It's typescript alright, and there's nothing that is missing in it, just that there's an error there (see my answer below). Not sure why people down voted the question or voted to close it, it's perfectly fine. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by TJ, the `: Object` part is either [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [Flow](https://flowtype.org/).

> To be precise, I'm talking about those function arguments:

I believe you are talking about [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). They allow you to assign default values to the parameters of a function.

Basic usage:

```
function sayHi (name = 'John') {
  console.log('Hi ' + name)
}

sayHi('James') // Hi James
sayHi() // Hi John
```

When you are destructuring an object, you can also use default parameters.

Example:

```
function printInfo ({ name = 'John', age = 30 }) {
  console.log('Name: ' + name)
  console.log('Age: ' + age)
}

printInfo({ name: 'James', age: 10 }) // Name: James, Age: 10
printInfo({ age: 20 }) // Name: John, Age: 20
printInfo({ name: 'Michael' }) // Name: 'Michael', age: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

It's typescript alright, but it's not valid typescript as it produces an error when compiled, and it's [deconstructing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring) indeed, or more specifically [object destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring) using [default values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#default-values).
The reason that it does not compile is that the type of the parameter is `Object` which won't allow anything that isn't indexed, for example:

```
let o: Object = { a: 5 };
console.log(o.a); // Error: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Object'
console.log(o["a"]); // this is fine
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20o%3A%20Object%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%205%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(o.a)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Property%20'a'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'Object'%0D%0Aconsole.log(o%5B%22a%22%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20fine))

Change it to `any` and it will work just fine:

```
function defaultPort({ port=123, user='test' }: any = {}) { // no error
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20defaultPort(%7B%20port%3D123%2C%20user%3D'test'%20%7D%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D))

Though it will probably be best to just declare the type:

```
type Param = {
    port?: number;
    user?: string;
}

function defaultPort({ port=123, user='test' }: Param = {}) {
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Param%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09port%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09user%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20defaultPort(%7B%20port%3D123%2C%20user%3D'test'%20%7D%3A%20Param%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D))