# How to define optional constructor arguments with defaults in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to have optional constructor arguments with default value, like this

```
export class Test {
    constructor(private foo?: string="foo", private bar?: string="bar") {}
}
```

This gives me the following error:

Parameter cannot have question mark and initializer.

I would like to create instances like

```
x = new Test();               // x.foo === 'foo'            
x = new Test('foo1');         // x.foo === 'foo1'
x = new Test('foo1', 'bar1');
```

What is the correct typescript way to achieve this?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

An argument which has a default value is optional by definition, as [stated in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters):

> Default-initialized parameters that come after all required parameters
>   are treated as optional, and just like optional parameters, can be
>   omitted when calling their respective function

It's the same for constructors as it is for other functions, so in your case:

```
export class Test {
    constructor(private foo: string = "foo", private bar: string = "bar") {}
}
```

Comment: `private foo = "foo", private bar = "bar"` I guess the type can be inferred here.

Comment: in my own personal preference I liketo always type define even when it's obvious

Comment: How do you do this with destructured parameters, as succintly as possible, without [duplicating the list of destructured fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314806/setting-default-value-for-typescript-object-passed-as-argument/32596200#32596200)?

Answer (score 7):

You can add question mark after your args, which is cleaner. If you add default parameters, it should be optional by default.

```
export class Test {
   foo: string; 
   bar: string;

    constructor(foo?: string, bar?: string) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
   }
}
```

Comment: Unclear if this worked at the time, but now compilation fails with this error: `error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: Don't agree with comment that variables with default parameter "should be optional by default". Default parameters are to provide a default value to a variable being passed into a function. A variable that is optional does NOT need to have a default value.