# How to handle failed API contracts in frontend applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have developed several frontend applications and as I analyse I often need to refactor the front-end code or frontend crash in the following case:

Let's assume there is a endpoint `/movies` that returns the following response:

```
{
  "movieName": "Avengers Endgame",
  "genre": "Action, Thriller",
  "length": 120 // in minutes 
  "rating": 4,
  "id": 1
}
```

To handle this endpoint's response in the frontend application (React + Typescript), I have created a `MovieType` and will render the data in the component.

```
// types.ts

  export type MovieType = {
    movieName: string;
    genre: string;
    length: number;
    rating: number;
    id: number;
  }
```

```
import React from 'react';

function MovieComponent() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = React.useState([] as MovieType[]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data:MovieType[] = fetchDataSomeHow() as MovieType[];
    setMovies(data);
  })

  return (
    <ul>
      movies.map(movie => (
        <li key={movie.id}>
          {movie.movieName.toLoweCase()} - {movie.rating}
        </li>
      ))

    </ul>
  )
}
```

So here I have created `MovieType` by looking at the response of the `/movies` endpoint and marked `movieName` as required in `MovieType`. Here the `MovieType` is affected by the data returned by the `/movies` endpoint.

As I am using Typescript and I have defined `movieName` as `string` and `required`, I can use `toLowerCase` method without any additional checks.

Now let's suppose that there is some bad input in the movie database and in the response  `movieName` is `undefined/null` or `movieName` is changed to `name`. Now the frontend application will crash because of runtime errors.

This happens whenever there is an API contract mismatch in the frontend and backend because of bad database entries or sudden backend API changes.

is there any standard or a good way to handle this kind of errors? I can easily make every field optional and then write frontend code but it will be messy and nonreadble. On the backend side, we have concepts of adapters that validate and sanitise the data and throws errors in case of invalid requests but on the frontend side, we can't hang users on an error page just because we got one field wrong in one object among 1000 objects.

Comment: Perhaps [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) would work for you?

Comment: If you don't want the front-end to fail, you should have a fallback value. Say "-", if the movie name is missing. Usually, there will be a mapping stage between front-end objects and whatever is returned from the API instead of blindly pointing the API response to the front-end object. During that map, you can validate and assign empty/null fallback values. Yes, it is easy to take whatever comes over way but it is better to validate and map each field I think.

Comment: @SanishJoseph - that is exactly what conditional types will help to accomplish.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Will it automatically assign the fallback value? Say `movieName: string | null | "-"`. Is there a way I can get "-" when `movieName` is null without explicitly assigning "-"?

Comment: Yes, it can be done - follow the link I provided above and search for `default` on that page. The single result describes how to do this.

Comment: Maybe an example according to the question or an answer will help. I still couldn't get the idea.

Comment: @SanishJoseph so do you mean that I should follow a kind of controller-model approach where controller fetches data and convert it to a model. This model is object that fronted can use without any additional checks as all the validation is done already?

Comment: @RandyCasbum I think conditional types won't solve the issue. The basic concept with types is that they only exists for compile time and not at the runtime. So according to question, I have mentioned that MovieType will always have movieName but API contract failed at runtime so typescript can't help me here.

Comment: You may handle it with an interface and a class with a constructor which accepts all values from the response and sets the values based on availability. The constructor may have some default values set to handle the null cases. Just thinking the OOPs way.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326380/how-to-define-optional-constructor-arguments-with-defaults-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can check if movie exists using && check:

```js
movie && {movie.movieName.toLoweCase()} - {movie.rating}
```

Comment: This is not feasible solution. If there are 100 keys and 20 APIs then adding conditional statements will make the code really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I would classify the type as [unknown](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type). Big picture, you are getting something, and you don't know what it is. So it's unknown. After you do this, Typescript will force you to check everything, then you get all the benefits of the typed result.

You could still define the type

```
export type MovieType = {
    movieName: string;
    genre: string;
    length: number;
    rating: number;
    id: number;
  }
```

But your result from the API would initially be `unknown`. After you get your result, you would [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the result. The `unknown` type will protect you from mistakes in this process. When it is appropriately narrowed, you could then assign it to a type of `MovieType` or work with those of that type.

```
const result: Record<string, unknown> = {
  movieName: "test",
};

export type MovieType = {
  movieName: string;
  genre: string;
  length: number;
  rating: number;
  id: number;
};

let someMovie: MovieType | undefined;

if (
  typeof result === "object" &&
  typeof result.movieName === "string" &&
  typeof result.genre === "string" &&
  typeof result.length === "number" &&
  typeof result.rating === "number" &&
  typeof result.id === "number"
) {
  someMovie = {
    movieName: result.movieName,
    genre: result.genre,
    length: result.length,
    rating: result.rating,
    id: result.id,
  };
}
```

Unfortunately I could not directly just use type `unknown` and narrow it all the way to a `Record<string, unknown>`. I asked [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70028907/narrowing-an-object-of-type-unknown) on this, but I think it may be impossible currently.