# Narrowing an object of type unknown

Tags: typescript

I have read multiple posts and issues on here with respect to narrowing an `object` of type `unknown` in TypeScript. But I have not found this specific question or solution.

Most solutions I find state to do something like this.

```
const result: unknown = {
  movieName: "test",
};

if (
  typeof result === "object" &&
  result !== null &&
  "movieName" in result &&
  typeof result.movieName === "string" // <-- Error Here
) {}
```

The error states

> Property 'movieName' does not exist on type 'object'

How do I narrow it so that it knows that the `unknown` thing is an `object` which contains the property `movieName`? How do I access `result.movieName` for an `unknown` type?

edit: [perhaps it's not possible?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38801) and the recommendation in the comments below of declaring it as a Record<string, unknown> may be the only way per this [GitHub request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25720)?

Comment: maybe you can use `result: Record<string, unknown> `

Comment: The type up there is simply for testing. The unknown result actually comes from an API.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR TS4.9+

TypeScript 4.9 will introduce support for [`in` operator narrowing of unlisted properties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#in-narrowing), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#50666](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50666), as a fix for [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) mentioned below.  At that point the above code will just work without modification:

```
const result: unknown = {
    movieName: "test",
};

if (
    typeof result === "object" &&
    result !== null &&
    "movieName" in result &&
    typeof result.movieName === "string" // <-- okay
) {
    result.movieName.toUpperCase(); // <-- okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgVwDZQFw2WA1mEAdzBgF4YBvAKBlpgFsQA3ASwQDkBDehLAIihIofADRUAvgG4qVFgDMYAChp0oATwAOCEAsQp0ZUuT4gARgCsEwYTABktlbT1pYAQiMwwaVHYd0YfIysHNwIfDAsJM4G9o4w6lo68EguAHRBbFw8hsbQcJEA5uEA9MUwADwAtJUwILicalQAlJRx0VDpzJmhqVAgAKoaWnAAwpwQCIpN0uJAA)

---

### PREVIOUS ANSWER FOR TS4.8-

This is currently a missing feature in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) for the relevant feature request.  Right now when you use the [`in` operator as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) like `k in result`, it only really does any meaningful narrowing if the type of `result` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where some members are known to have the key `k` and others are not.  It does not assert the existence of a property with key `k`.  So in your case, where the type of `result` is just `object` (narrowed from `unknown`), nothing meaningful happens.

The workaround I sometimes use is to write my own [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which behaves the way I want `in` to behave.  For example:

```
function hasKey<K extends string, T extends object>(
    k: K, o: T
): o is T & Record<K, unknown> {
    return k in o;
}
```

Now, instead of writing `k in result`, I write `hasKey(k, result)`:

```
if (
    typeof result === "object" &&
    result !== null &&
    hasKey("movieName", result) &&
    typeof result.movieName === "string" // okay
) {
    result.movieName.toUpperCase(); // okay
}
```

This works how you want, and is arguably the closest you can get to type safety here, at least until something is done to address microsoft/TypeScript#21732 natively.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgVwDZQFw2WA1mEAdzBgF4YBvAWACgZ6YBbEANwEsEA5AQ0YSwBEUJFAEAaWgF8A3LVoAzHMChtwMABbcIAaQQBPADzaYCAB7CwAEwgxocNmADmYmABUT5hFZsgARgCsEZQA+AApaBhhcLG0XECxXWgBKLBAYNht3ADIYACUgkDhLIxccfCIwYMoIhkQoZDgSXHSSEFkaSTkaNnkYcLoGKD0ABwQQXsQUdDJScgE-QOUBGCysmvpJtFgAQlmYMDRUFbWB+k0dfVCBZnYuXgRxeCQtpOP1mCHR8aepqAA6G4cHh8GZzOwORzLAD0UJgIFw3D0yWqpx+WwBrCB9z+UBAAFVhqM4ABhLQIUJJaQwGFwhFIjpdIA)

Comment: This is working well for me. Is there a way to combine the the first three steps into another type checking function? A function such as `isObjectWithKey` that checks that it is not null and is an object then runs hasKey? Thank you for the help.

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbGb3W), sure.  If you need anything further, you might consider posting a new questions, since comment sections of previous answers aren't always the best place to get followup answers.