# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CountdownComponent: (?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am trying to build a simple component within my app for a countdown. i keep getting this uncaught error whenever i ng serve. please a little help, i am stomped

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './content/content.component';
import { CountdownComponent } from './countdown/countdown.component';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    CountdownComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<app-count></app-count>
```

countdown.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-count',
templateUrl: './countdown.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./countdown.component.css']
})

export class CountdownComponent {
dayleft: 100;

constructor(days: any) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        days = this.dayleft;
        days--;
    }, 1000);
}
}
```

countdown.component.html

```
<p>{{ daysleft }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that right to add `days` as a pramater to class constructor but here you are not the one how create and initialise the `CountdownComponent` instant angular do that for you,that why you got an error **Can't resolve all parameters for CountdownComponent: (?)** , when you add a pramater to componenet constracter angular try to inject by Angular DI system,in this case you may create inject value and provid this to class constructor by @Inject decorator.

*create inject value*

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, CountComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:[{provide:'days',useValue:100}]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*component*

```
export class CountComponent implements OnInit {

  id: any; // to clear setInterval 
  constructor( @Inject('days') private days: number) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = setInterval(() => {
      --this.days
      if (this.days === 0) {
        clearInterval(this.id)
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

}
```

count template

```
{{days}}
```

app component

```
<app-count></app-count>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inject-countdown)

Another solution is create Input property and use it like @Suren Srapyan said

Comment: Preferable approach. Exactly what i was hoping to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Remove `days` from the constructor parameter and pass it via `@Input`. Angular can't inject `days: any` in the constructor. I think also you don't need `daysleft` property.

```
export class CountdownComponent {

   @Input() days;

   constructor() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.days--;
      }, 1000);
   }

}
```

and use like

```
<app-count [days]="100"></app-count>
```

Here `100` will be passed into the `CountdownComponent` and initialize `days` property with `100`.

Answer (score 1):

**The reason behind the error:**

When the angular finds the tag `<app-count></app-count>`, he will tries to initialize the component `CountdownComponent` by matching the html tag with the selector property in the `CountdownComponent` decorator. This means that the angular code will try to do something like this:

```
let countdownComponent: CountdownComponent = new CountdownComponent()
```

Because you define the days as a mandatory parameter, the angular does not know how to resolve the parameters that you define and that causes the error.

**First solution:**

You can tell to the angular witch is the value of the days by using the [@Input decorator](https://toddmotto.com/passing-data-angular-2-components-input) and by passing in the HTML which value will be passed.

```
<app-count [days]=100></app-count>

export class CountdownComponent {
    @Input()
    dayleft: number = 100;

    constructor(days: any) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            days = this.dayleft;
            days--;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

**Second solution:**
You can set the parameters as [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734509/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-in-typescript-while-omitting-some-other-optional) or [default parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314806/setting-default-value-for-typescript-object-passed-as-argument)

```
constructor(days: any = 100) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        days = this.dayleft;
        days--;
    }, 1000);
}

//or

constructor(days?: any) {
    if(!days) days = 100;
    setTimeout(() => {
        days = this.dayleft;
        days--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: the second solution fits perfectly. Much appreciation for your time

Comment: Thank you @mitch. Each time you like an answer upvotes. Also, if you think that the answer solves your issue, please accepted as the best answer