# Why is the object possibly undefined in typescript, when an explicit undefined check is added via function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Below is a small example, where I would like to ask, why the eslinter for typescript is complaining about the object, that it could be possibly undefined in that case, where an undefined-check is actually added, just that it is extracted into a separate function, so that is gets a more meaningful name.

```
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface Item {
  id?: string;
  images?: string[];
}

const itemHasImages = (item: Item): boolean =>
  item.images !== undefined && item.images.length > 0;

const renderItem = (item: Item): ReactElement => {
  if(itemHasImages(item)){ // <<< using this the compiler complains below in JSX that item could possibly be null
    // vs if(item.images !== undefined && item.images.length > 0) <<< here the compiler recognizes the check
    return (
      <>
        <img src={item.images[0]} alt={""} />
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return <></>
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const dummyItems = [
    {
      images: ["https://picsum.photos/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/200/300"]
    },
    {
      images: ["https://picsum.photos/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/200/300"]
    }
  ];

  if (itemHasImages(dummyItems[0])) {
    console.log("hello")
    renderItem(dummyItems[0]);
  } else {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

Please apologize weak formatting, for better interaction you can find a code-sandbox link here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-bogdan-c74u6?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: One option is to extend the `Item` interface with one requiring `images` . `interface ItemWithImages extends Item {images: string[];} const itemHasImages = (item: Item): item is ItemWithImages => ...` [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sea-t7s45?file=/src/App.tsx). Generic discussion here: [Typescript user-defined type guard checking object has all properties in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872604/typescript-user-defined-type-guard-checking-object-has-all-properties-in-array)

Comment: also see: [Ensure existance of optional property in typescript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127082/ensure-existance-of-optional-property-in-typescript-interface)

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-stallman-gfo0i?file=/src/App.tsx) implementing the above, voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

In your posted code Typescript has no way of knowing that the `boolean` returned from your function is intended as a type guard for the `item` object.

To solve this you can declare a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) as the return type of your function indicating that Typescript should interpret the returned boolean as an assertion of the predicate. You will need to have a type/interface that describes an `item` with a required `images` property to use in the predicate.

You can either do this explicitly by extending the `Item` interface and making the `images` property required. ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sea-t7s45?file=/src/App.tsx:62-603), [ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYCiANkiEgHbwC+cAZlBCHAERQEwsDcAsAFD9gVJFDrokcAJIwyufnDjAAJgH4AXHADOMKEIDmvPgtAo9STeq079AbQC6h6v0HDR4qTJAB1YDAAWkiCm5nBIAB4yFEqaHrI48opBZpoa2roUevaOznx0AK4UGMAQFIqeABIomoHBmgAUvmQa0mQAlBqNzMAxLd6+AUkh8UZw7DB5UKWdAHQmyXAAhAC8S3AFSkh0QkhKcABke2Vks4Oa06QZ-nAAfHAADNkCfGgl2qOUG1C9cKsNns2edr4dAwEhkSjwJa3YbGOhwP5kSrVU4IkCtVpyEYKMYTUp1BIKBQAHmuBMJxNAei0UDQSxwMzm5hsdzstBQxBgdJYLFoAHpSVjCUT+WTWoYFLQkMRNBIYYScZM4CThddxXAnHxqFwgA))

```
interface Item {
  id?: string;
  images?: string[];
}

interface ItemWithImages extends Item {
  images: string[];
}

function itemHasImages(item: Item): item is ItemWithImages {
  return item.images !== undefined && item.images.length > 0;
}

const renderItem = (item: Item): ReactElement => {
  if (itemHasImages(item)) {
    // vs if(item.images !== undefined && item.images.length > 0) <<< here the compiler recognizes the check
    return (
      <>
        <img src={item.images[0]} alt={""} />
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return <></>;
  }
};
```

Or you can implement the utility type described in the [flagged duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127082/ensure-existance-of-optional-property-in-typescript-interface) which converts an optional property to a required one. ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-stallman-gfo0i?file=/src/App.tsx), [ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYCiANkiEgHbwC+cAZlBCHAERQEwsDcAsAFD8A9ACph-OMLgABAM5IkcABYwYYGQC5BgmTHQBrCADckUOsQgB3AHRomggI4BXJDuAQKMwQFYATAEYfAHYABgAOH0FKGUd2AFokAA9gHRQKNCRYiDpMsBg3ChRiWLBGMBMYAE9Y4ApYyrKZNChgXOqqEzp0JHFhQX56hQBZFD0kZCdgdgATAB4AFWwAaThEmEopmThRiqy4OYA+OABeOAAFYDQ9eexCBLRiRymkGe3dhbhF-cOAMnFcOAA2qc4DUPgBdWIAfnUcFu90ezzmQLB2EcFCedBqSCmh2ovAEfBqa1MXTgAEk1swcH9gFNoXAdM0KABzfFwEEgFDMlz0xk1ZkAsH46j8fh0NEYfIgykACRQMjJnO5MgAFMBKTCKWQAJQw9VkEGbYajcaOSbYmZakDYFigLkuFiHal8dnsGAxCjSshWO3KuAAQiOJzRGKxUzg32+XpAPqVLispBZMEUcEOwWFor4tg88HY6JMVuOcDVGvJlN1+HQMBIZEo8COTppdGL+pAcoVcdVre12twf1dSHdUE9Kv77LgM32Y-HE9AzIZUDQRxwrdj9pkAOCYNohRgy5YLFoginLpnE+PY+1bLgtCQxDkfdPA6HnsnM2P15FfDxQA))

```
/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127082/ensure-existance-of-optional-property-in-typescript-interface
 */
 type MakeRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> &
 { [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[P], undefined> };

interface Item {
 id?: string;
 images?: string[];
}

function itemHasImages(item: Item): item is MakeRequired<Item, "images"> {
 return item.images !== undefined && item.images.length > 0;
}

const renderItem = (item: Item): ReactElement => {
 if (itemHasImages(item)) {
   // vs if(item.images !== undefined && item.images.length > 0) <<< here the compiler recognizes the check
   return (
     <>
       <img src={item.images[0]} alt={""} />
     </>
   );
 } else {
   return <></>;
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why the eslinter for typescript is complaining about the object, that it could be possibly undefined?

The reason is because you added a ? (optional) to the property in the interface declaration.

One way to fix it is to check for undefined when rendering it with the ? operator.

```
<img src={item.images ? item.images[0] : ""} alt={""} />
```

Note that is only hiding the issue, the real solution is to make sure you don't render that element if there're no images, i.e. add a `!!item.images?.length` check.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately TypeScript does not understand what your function `itemHasImages` exactly does, even if it has the exact same body as an expression that TS may understand when it is inlined.

Therefore when you factorize your check in an external function, TypeScript can no longer use it to perform type narrowing (here to make sure that an optional property is actually present).

This is one of the cases where TypeScript may force us not to be "too smart" and leave an inline check.

Another acceptable solution is to force / cast the type after your check:

```
  if(itemHasImages(item)){
    const images = item.images as unknown as string[]; // Force type since we have externally verified it
    return (
      <>
        <img src={images[0]} alt={""} />
      </>
    );
  }
```

A more complex solution *might* be possible, by providing overload definitions for your `itemHasImages` function, so that TS can use them to perform type narrowing.