# How to set default value of props if not passed to functional component in NextJS using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

This is the component:

```
const defaultDesc = "welcome to homepage";

    export default function Header(Props: {
       title:string,
      desc?:string
    }): JSX.Element {
    
    }
```

If I don't pass `desc` in `<Header>` then I'd like to set `defaultDesc` value by default. One way to that is to check for empty value of `desc` and then set it to `defaultDesc`.
But, is there any other efficient way which avoids multiple checks in case passing many props.

```
      <Header
        title="Homepage"
      />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define an interface and destructure the Props with the default value in case Props don't have optional argument passed to the Component as

```
const defaultDesc = "welcome to homepage";

interface  HeaderProps{
       title:string,
      desc?:string
}

export default function Header(Props: HeaderProps): JSX.Element {
    
const { title, desc= defaultDesc } = Props;   // you can use let, however const is recommended


}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39114055/7344164)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the default props syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I am passing two (min 1 variable with default value) or more parameters to the function as argument I create `interface`/`type` for them to be more readable.

In this case, I would have done something like this.

```
const defaultDesc = "welcome to homepage";

interface Props {
    title: string,
    desc?: string,
}

export default function Header({
    title,
    desc=defaultDesc // this is what you are looking for
}: Props): JSX.Element {

    // rest of the logic
    // ...
}
```